# Rewrite profile URL making whole page glitch and break

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Alright I've searched and looked at at least 20 ways to turn site.com/profile?page=username
to just site.com/username
and they DO work, but when I do it and go to the page it starts off loading normal, then completely glitches and continues to glitch and break the page.

I really don't know what to do at this point. I don't know if it's just GoDaddy and I need something specific or what.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+) /profile.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?page=$1
```

is the current one i've tried

---

#### Solved

I ended up finding someone who posted this, and it worked!

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /profile.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: .htaccess is witchcraft, I usually copy parts that work from other .htaccess files, until I get what I want.

Comment: What does "glitch" mean. You have to be specific about the problem. And how do you know the site supports having the username in your preferred format? Maybe it's expecting it as `page=`.

Comment: Like the footer, and header and some of the page overlay each other and move around the page with different opacities.

Comment: and site.com/profile/username works for me perfectly fine, so i just assumed site.com/username would as well

Comment: @user3478701 That's a pretty terrible assumption, ridiculously bad assumption. And how are we supposed to help you with a glitch without even the tiniest bit of information?

Comment: #1 no reason to be hostile #2 my assumption was correct, it does work that way, if you would scroll up you can see the problem was resolved by a code I recently found. thanks though